# Solve the integral $\int_0^1\left [\lambda_n\cos(\lambda_nx)+h\sin(\lambda_n(x)\right ]^2\mathrm{dx}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given $(\lambda^2-h^2)\sin\lambda=2h\lambda\cos\lambda \tag{1}$
Solve the integral $\int_0^1\left [\lambda_n\cos(\lambda_nx)+h\sin(\lambda_n(x)\right ]^2\mathrm{dx}\tag{2}$

The answer should be $\frac{\lambda_n^2+2h+h^2}{2}$

This is from Zill's, Differential equations and boundary value problems chapter 12.7 problem 8, where the answer is given with $\alpha$ instead of $\lambda$ and you have to prove the solution of the PDE.

After squaring (2) I get $\int_0^1\lambda^2\cos^2(\lambda x)+2\lambda h\sin(\lambda x)cos(\lambda x)+h^2\sin^2(\lambda x)\tag{3}$

Using the formulas $\sin^2x=.5(1-\cos(2x))$ and  $\cos^2x=.5(1+\cos(2x))dx$ and integrating:
$$\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\frac{\lambda^2\sin(2\lambda)}{4\lambda} +h\sin^2(\lambda) +\frac{h^2}{2}-\frac{h^2\sin(2\lambda)}{4\lambda}\tag{4}$$
Plugging in (1) to (4)
$$\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\frac{2h\lambda\cos(2\lambda)}{4\lambda}+h\sin^2(\lambda)+\frac{h^2}{2}$$
Using the half-angle formula and combining:
$$\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\frac{2h\lambda(\cos^2(\lambda)-\sin^2(\lambda))+4\lambda h\sin^2(\lambda)}{4\lambda}+\frac{h^2}{2}$$
Using $sin^2+cos^2=1$
$$\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\frac{2h\lambda}{4\lambda}+\frac{h^2}{2}$$
$$\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\frac{h}{2}+\frac{h^2}{2}$$

Does anyone see where the error is? $\frac{h}{2}$ should be $\frac{2h}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is when plugging $(1)$ to $(4)$.

You have $$\frac{(\lambda^2-h^2)\sin(2\lambda)}{4\lambda}=\frac{2(\lambda^2-h^2)\sin(\lambda)\cos(\lambda)}{4\lambda}=\frac{4h\lambda \cos^2(\lambda)}{4\lambda}=h\cos^2(\lambda)$$thus you will get $$\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+h\left(\sin^2(\lambda)+\cos^2(\lambda)\right)+\frac{h^2}{2}=\frac{\lambda^2+2h+h^2}{2}$$

Comment: Hey Galc, you answered a question on my old email account last year. Small world huh?